# Python on windows subprocess don´t work

Tags: python, subprocess, password-protection, unrar

I want test to  open a winrar password protected file, testing with dictionay of words.
This is my code, but it don't work can any help me ? thanks

```
import subprocess
def extractFile(rFile, password):
try:
    subprocess.call(['c:\\mio\\unrar\\unrar.exe -p'+password+'x C:\\mio\\unrar\\'+rFile,'shell=True'])
    return password
except:
    return
def main():    
rFile = "c:\\mio\\unrar\msploit.rar"
passFile = open("C:\\mio\\unrar\\dic.txt")
for line in passFile.readlines():
    password = line.strip('\n')

    guess = extractFile(rFile, password)
    print(password)
    if guess:
       print '[+] Password = ' + password + '\n'
       break
if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Comment: you have to indent the `main()` line (the last one)

Comment: Can you please explain wha tdo you mean by `doesn't work`? Please be more specific when asking about a problem with your code.

Comment: @CharlesB and other lines as well.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by putting `, 'shell=True'` into the array instead of giving it properly as an argument to the function?

Comment: In my response you will see that `call()` has wrong arguments, but I think that even when `call()` succeeds you may not guess password correctly and then probably `unrar` will display some error and will not create output file.

Answer (score 1):

First argument to `call()` is an array but you use full command. Try something like:

```
subprocess.call(['unrar.exe', 'x', '-p'+password, rarfn], shell=True)
```

**EDIT:**

I think you will also have to check if output file is created. Maybe `unrar` with incorrect password will not create output file. Check if it is created (for example use `os.path.isfile()`). You can also examine `unrar` output to see where is the problem.

**EDIT2:**

It seems that there was no *x* `rar` command to *Extract files with full path*.

This is working example where I rar-ed with password file `Order.htm` into `Order.rar` and then I deleted `Order.htm`:

```
rarfn = 'Order.rar'
outfn = 'Order.htm'
if os.path.isfile(outfn):
    print('%s already exists!!!' % (outfn))
else:
    for password in ('ala', 'ma', 'kota', 'zorro', 'rudy'):
        print('testing %s...' % (password))
        subprocess.call(['unrar.exe', 'x', '-p'+password, rarfn], shell=True)
        if os.path.isfile(outfn):
            print('guessed: [%s]' % (password))
            break
```

Comment: Thanks, unrar in dos mode works ok with unrar -ppassword xfile.rar, but in subprocess call, putting this:subprocess.call(['c:\\mio\\unrar\\unrar.exe ', '-p',password,' xC:\\mio\\unrar\\',rFile]) opens a dos windows but waiting a password manually